# Moving a tag using the Google Maps API on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using a `HelloItemizedOverlay` to plot a tag of my location on a Google map.

Now, if the tag is moved, I want to remove it and plot a new one.

How do I remove this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `LocationListener` in your activity to get users current latitude and longitude.

Create geopoint using this latitude and longitude(in onLocationChanged method) and make OverlayItem of this. and pass this overlayItem to your HelloItemizedOverlay.

```
 overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Text","Snippet");
        helloItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
```

this will pin on your current location and will create new pin again once your location is changed.

Comment: Hi the point is , I am getting 3 or 4 people's locations and plotting them... when they move, many points are created.. I want the GeoPoints to be updated , not created newly ! Pl help thanks

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude from the server and not from my network_provider  !! HELP !

Comment: you must have called `mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();` and later you add your helloItemizedOverlay in that. So next time  mapView.getOverlays(); gets called it already contains pins of your helloItemizedOverlay. So by any means make the mapOverlay final or any way to make it get called only once. so next time you change points in your helloItemizedOverlay it will get added in final getOverlays.(I Hope i did not confused you)